# How to print local attributes in a Python traceback? (not just frame's locals)

Tags: python, traceback

I modified traceback.print_exception to output the locals for the last frame:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aconrad/work/smlib.traceback/tests.py", line 287, in test_display_variable_that_is_not_local
    f.boom()
  File "/home/aconrad/work/smlib.traceback/tests.py", line 284, in boom
    return ','.join(self.foo)
TypeError

    local variables:
    - self: <tests.Foo object at 0x3233350>
```

In the case above, the locals are not useful enough as I don't know the value of self.foo which broke the join() function. I would like to modify my custom traceback to also print the attributes used and their values, as followed:

```
    attributes:
    - self.foo: 1
```

I started parsing the source using the ast module to find the attributes and look them up in the frame's locals. It works for my one use-case above, but it's too fragile to support any source lines. What's the best way to achieve this?

Here is the code I used for my test case:

```py
class Foo(object):
    foo = 1

    def boom(self):
        return ','.join(self.foo)

f = Foo()
f.boom()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list of attributes and method of the current object if you match a self in your local variable list:

```
if and isinstance(current_var, object) and str(current_var) == 'self':  # avoid to list every objects encountered...
    print '\n'.join(["%s: %s" % (i, getattr(f, i)) for i in dir(f) if not i.startswit
h('__')])
```

You can filter by checking if `getattr(f, i)` is not a function (to avoid some lines like `boom: <bound method Foo.boom of <__main__.Foo object at 0x0000000001E2B908>>`).

It not the best solution I guess but it should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response Maxime! Although I'd only want to display the values from in the traceback source that may have caused the error. 'self' might not be part of the statement, so I don't just want to look at self, but anything that broke the statement: ','.join(something.foo)

Comment: Only if you parse the last line to get every identifier used and play with `getattr()`, it will be difficult I guess.